# TreeViewItem adding nodes

Tags: c#, wpf

My attempt at adding nodes to a WPF treeview programmatically is not working as expected i.e., for the code below I expected to have leaf nodes "C14-5 and "C14-6" under "C1-4" and "C2-4" whereas they appear under the root node "Level-0"

```
public class CSTree 
{
    public class CS_TREE
    {
        int nodeId; int parentId, string description;
        public CS_TREE(int node, int parent, string desc)
        {
            nodeId = node; parentId = parent; description = desc;
        }
        public int NodeId { get { return nodeId;}
        public int ParentId { get { return parentId;}
        public int Description { get { return description;}
    }
```

`private static List<CS_TREE> tree = new List<CS_TREE>() new {
    new CS_TREE(1,0,"Level-0"),
    new CS_TREE(2,1,"Level-1 A"),
    new CS_TREE(3,1,"Level-1 B"),
    new CS_TREE(4,1,"Level-1 C"),   
    new CS_TREE(5,4,"Level-2 C1-4"),
    new CS_TREE(6,4,"Level-2 C2-4"),
    new CS_TREE(7,5,"Level-3 C14-5"),
    new CS_TREE(7,6,"Level-3 C24-6"),
}

public void PopulateTreeView()
{
    foreach (CS_TREE cst in L_tree)
    {
        AddToTree(cst);
    }
}

public void AddToTree(CS_TREE cst)
{
    var subitem = new TreeViewItem() { Header = cst.Description, Tag = cst};
    if (cst.ParentId == 0)
    {
        _rootNode = new TreeViewItem() { Header = cst.Description, Tag = cst };
    }
    else
    {
        TreeViewItem node = FindNode(_rootNode, cst);
        if (node != null)
        {
            node.Items.Add(subitem);
        }
        else
        {
            _rootNode.Items.Add(subitem);
        }
    }
}

private TreeViewItem FindNode(TreeViewItem rootNode, CS_TREE cst)
{
    TreeViewItem rv = null;
    if (rootNode != null && rootNode.HasItems)
    {
        var items = rootNode.Items;
        foreach (TreeViewItem item in items)
        {
            CS_TREE nodeCST = item.Tag as CS_TREE;
            if (nodeCST.NodeId == cst.ParentId)
            {
                return item;
            }
            else if (item.HasItems)
            {
                FindNode(item, cst);
            }
        }
    }
    return rv;
}

private TreeViewItem _rootNode = null;
public TreeViewItem Root
{
    get { return _rootNode; }
}`

}

Could readers point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return the found node.
So instead of

```
FindNode(item, cst);
```

do

```
rv = FindNode(item, cst);
if (rv != null)
    return rv;
```

Additionally you are using the same NodeId 7 in nodes "C14-5" and "C24-6".

So if you want any nodes under "C24-6", you should write

```
new CS_TREE(8,6,"Level-3 C24-6"),
```